# SQL select into delete DIRECTLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-delete

I need to select records, check my select criteria and enhance it until I got all records I need, and then delete (or otherwise change) those. Let's go with delete for the moment.

```
select <fields> from <database> where <condition>
```

(check, adjust condition)

```
delete from <database> where (<same condition>)
```

Isn't here an easier way, like pipes for instance, to shove the selected records directly into the delete statement? I used techniques selecting all record numbers into a temporary database, but isn't there an direct way?

I searched Stack Overflow, and found several questions where people ask how to convert a select statement into a delete statement, this is not what I want. What I have in mind is something like:

```
select ... from ... where ... | delete
```

or maybe something like this as a workaround ...

```
/* create a list of records to delete */
select ... from ... where ... into @temp

/* shove the list into delete */
delete @temp
```

Does the SQL standard support mechanisms for what I want, or is there maybe a platform specific approach (MS SQL Server)?

Comment: But why select data that you don't want to keep? Can't you just delete it?

Comment: If you want to select something based on some condition - do select. If you want to delete using some condition - do delete. Why bother mixing it and invent new syntax, pipes and so on?

Comment: @jarlh Essentially, he's using SQL interactively, so for his (narrow) use-case, and with his particular mindset, it makes sense. I imagine he's come from a scripting background (Bash, PowerShell, something like that). OP - please feel free to correct me if I've misunderstood :)

Comment: @RB ... that's exactly my situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [**`Common Table Expression`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   select <fields>  
   from <table> 
   where <condition>
)
DELETE FROM CTE
```

This statement will delete *all records* returned by your query.

You can optionally add extra conditions applied to the in-line table returned by the CTE query, like:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   select <fields>  
   from <table> 
   where <condition>
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE <more conditions on CTE fields>
```

Comment: This works well and is very close to what I was looking for, thanks very much.

Tricky: the expression won't work without the leading ";" ...

Comment: ... Tricky: the expression won't work without the leading ";" ... if I omit it, I get a message like "Syntax error near the WITH keyword". Why this? I looked up both WITH and CTE syntax on the Microsoft T-SQL website ... they don't mention the leading ";".

But fact is, the statement won't work without it. Why is this?

Comment: @Nimral You have just encountered the only statement in tsql that requires a ';'! You **have** to place it right before the `WITH` in case there are other statements before the CTE.

Comment: Ah, d****, I found out myself. Way, way up the query editor window above a block of comments I wrote a "use <databasename>" statement, and forgot the ; there. That's why SQL complained at the next code line. Strange though that it didn't complain earlier, I can use select and delete statements while the ";" is still missing, but I can't use the WITH statement.

Comment: @Giorgios, thanks for your clarification, saw it after I punched in my response that I found out myself. The ONLY statement which requires a ; ... thats why you choose the arcane ;WITH notation, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact it seems you are performing some kind of manual manipulation of your data, I would suggest wrapping anything you do in a transaction. This will allow you to see the results of your statement before making it permanent.

```
SELECT * FROM [table];

BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [predicate];
SELECT * FROM [table];

ROLLBACK TRAN
--COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Neat idea, using transactions, didn't come to my mind. Thanks very much!