# SQL query to combine Select duplicates with count and grouping with delete based on Top but not the top 1 of each duplicate

Tags: sql, select, group-by, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I am looking to combine these 2 statement into one to run as a stored procedure if possible.
I have not used temp tables in queries before and may have to with this, not sure asking advice.
I did not write the original queries and manually run the first one which returns a table listing ID's with duplicate data nad how many records. Then each record ID is put into the 2nd query to remove all but the TOP 1 based on additional filtering criteria.

I have looked at using CTE from [SQL select into delete DIRECTLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458604/sql-select-into-delete-directly) but am stil at a loss on how to pass each result row ID value into the delete query.

The queries, edited for public consumption are

SELECT id, count(*) FROM [DEV].[dbo].[7dtest] where FileVer = 1 and CALC_DATE > FORMAT(DATEADD(DD,-7,GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd') group by id having count(*) > 1 order by count(*) desc

returns a table with id and number of duplicate rows
then take the id of each row and put into this delete statement

delete from [DEV].[dbo].[7dtest] where AutoID not in (
SELECT TOP 1 AutoID FROM [DEV].[dbo].[7dtest] where FileVer = 1 and id = '123' and CALC_DATE > FORMAT(DATEADD(DD,-7,GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
order by COMPLETED_DATE_CHECK_3 desc, COMPLETED_DATE_CHECK_2 desc, COMPLETED_DATE_CHECK_1 desc)
and FileVer = 1 and id = '123' and CALC_DATE > FORMAT(DATEADD(DD,-7,GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

Can this be done with CTE or do I need to create a temp table and some looping to get the ID one row at a time? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

TIA

Comment: Are there any rules on which record in each set of duplicates should be retained?

Comment: Yes, the rule is as in the delete query. The record to be retained will be the most recently changed one per the completed check value(s)(3 differnt values) and have the highest sequential ID number.